# (bitcoinj) How to determine which key/address to use to send funds?

Tags: bitcoinj

I'm using Bitcoinj and am confused as to the numerous addresses it's generating. I want to be able to send funds from my wallet (for which I have my private and public key) but I am unsure as to what address I should be using.

For example, I have an ECKey from which I can debug print a private or public key, but the wallet allows me to get four different addresses:

```
wallet.currentAddress(KeyChain.KeyPurpose.AUTHENTICATION)
wallet.currentAddress(KeyChain.KeyPurpose.REFUND)
wallet.currentAddress(KeyChain.KeyPurpose.CHANGE)
wallet.currentAddress(KeyChain.KeyPurpose.RECEIVE_FUNDS)
```

I understand I may not need to specify an address when creating the transaction (it seems that bitcoinj handles this?) but what address is associated with sending?

Apologies if this explanation doesn't make sense, I've been in crypto for a long time but the programming side is new to me.